# troubleshooting php contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form made with bootstrap, and a very simple script that post to self, but I can't get it to work, I uploaded to my site, but it is not posting the input fields back in the same page. 
here is the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Contact Us</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- stylesheet for this form -->
    <link href="contact-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="my-form">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
  <div class="form-group" id="hori-form">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
      </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>    
    </div> 
</form>
<?php
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; 
?>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing name html attribute for your input tags.

```
<input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
```

and this part of your page must change also

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"];?>
```

Comment: I made the changes, but when I hit send, I get this in the address bar http://pctechtips.org/test/<?php%20echo%20$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27];?>

Comment: what is the url before you click send?

Comment: Could you perhaps rename your file to contact2.php?

Comment: Also remove "<?php" on line 50 and "?>" on line 53

Comment: thanks, got it working... one more question, what is the correct way of handling form posting to self and having php script on the same page as form or posting to a different php page where the script is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75601/discussion-between-miatech-and-coenie-richards).